# Calculating regression weights from a covariance matrix

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, excel

My starting point is a covariance matrix (Not raw data) and I want to calculate the regression weights.  I may have as many as 6-8 independent variables and 1 dependent variable so looking for a matrix solution.  Been 20 years since I have done matrix algebra so any instructions for how to do this in Excel are appreciated.

Comment: @whuber I realize this is a very old thread, but this is not a duplicate of the above question. The asker wants "weights". They want to account for spatial autocorrelation or something similar and already have a variance-covariance matrix, generated from spatial coordinates.

Comment: @colin Your interpretation is inconsistent with the reply posted by the original questioner below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally stumbled on the answer.  For anyone else interested.  You start with a covariance matrix (or correlation matrix if you want standardized regression weights), and you use the minverse matrix formula of the X1 to Xi portion `{=MINVERSE(F44:H46)}` (look on youtube for how to use matrix formulas).  Then multiply this inversed $X^{-1}$ matrix by the $Y$ matrix from the covariance table `{=MMULT(F49:H51,E44:E46)}`.  That's it.  Will generate the $b$ weights that you need.  And from there its simple equations to get you to the $F$ and $t$, multiple $R$, etc. statistics.

Comment: The youtube URL?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMJOgopkLeY
This is a really good video that walks through from raw data to regression output in excel using matrices.  I was trying to find out how to work it from a covariance matrix since I have some missing data (pairwise) and from raw data will not work in Excel.  You'll notice that one of the intervening steps he has is the covariance X1-Xi matrix - it just wasnt labeled as such so it took me a while to figure out that's what it was.  He shows in detail how to use the minverse and mmult functions as well.